C# Analyzer, get type of instance an Operation is invoked on
I currently want to write a tiny analyzer, that validates some chainable method calls.
When using context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeOperationAction, OperationKind.Invocation); i'm able to hook into everything of the form x = test.doSth() and can retrieve quite a lot information from the semantic context, such as test, doSth(), doSth() is from class XY, doSth() returns a string etc.
However I want to know the type of test - just using the info doSth() is from class XY won't work for extension methods.
complete example:
class TestClazz
{
    public List<String> test2 { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new TestClazz();

    var x = test.test2.ToArray();
}

and the following Analyzer code is what I got so far, but even after hours i'm not able to make the "jump" from "test" to the Type "TestClazz"
private static void AnalyzeOperationAction(OperationAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var wholeExpression = context.Operation.Syntax; // test.test2.ToArray()
            var instance = wholeExpression.GetFirstToken(); // test

           //Invalid: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxToken' to 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode'   
            var type = context.Operation.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(instance); 

            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(MissingInitCallDescriptor, context.Operation.Syntax.GetLocation(), type);
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }

Any Idea, how to jump from 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxToken' to 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode' ?
I basically want to verify that test is instance of TestClazz before doing the actual checks and creating diagnostics.

Asking on SO always helps - answer is always found 5 Minutes later :P
var wholeExpression = context.Operation.Syntax; //test.test2.ToArray();
var instance = wholeExpression.GetFirstToken(); //test
var type = context.Operation.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(instance.Parent).Type; //App.Programm.TestClazz

(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxToken is a part of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode, or say, every node is made out of multiple Tokens. Hence, token.parent provides the required Node-Type to use to query for the TypeInfo-Object.
